# Data Format for future Big Data Analytics with Hadoop

Tags: azure, hadoop, avro, azure-hdinsight, bigdata

After reading a bit about various data formats which are more or less suitable for working with Hadoop it appears that Apache Avro seems to be a nice option since it is a splittable container format.

So such an Avro file that one could store in HDFS could look something like this:

```
{
   Header
   Message1
   Message2
   Message3
   ....
}
```

(Those Messages represent some raw data from IoT devices)

Hadoop would then be able to process Message1-3 in parallel on different nodes (at least this is how I imagine this)

Now my question: Can I just use any format for those Messages, even non splittable ones as e.g. Protobuf or does it still somehow makes sense to use Avro (splittable) for the messages themselves? Are there any advantages in doing so?
What is your experience?

**EDIT**: for now there is no concrete scenario on what insights could be gained from the raw data. The system is supposed to store the raw data NOW and analytics might come in a year or two. I just want to have a solution that will work in the future.

Answer (score -2):

Avro format stores the data schema in JSON format thus, in terms of Key-Value pairs and in terms of actual storage of data it stores them as serialized raw binary format. Thus, in terms of working if your application requires large data set with splittable and serialized storage requirement avro goes with it. If your application is more statistical computation intensive you can go for ORC2 or parquet. Please elaborate your use case to answer according to your requirement.

Comment: slightly confusing as you menttion "Avro format stores the data in JSON format" above. Where as it is just the Avro schema that is stored in JSON  and data in compact binary representation (so that there is no overhead per value when datum is written).